# npm is complaining about imports outside modules. What does that mean?

Tags: node.js, module, mocha.js

As a personal project, I am trying to learn some basic javascript programming by implementing an online version of the card game "Great Dalmuti".

Right now, I'm trying to implement some basic elements from the game using TDD. You can see the current state of my code at: https://github.com/spierepf/great-dalmuti

The issue that I am having is with the statement:

```
import { INVALID_MOVE } from 'boardgame.io/core';
```

which I copy-pasted from the boardgame.io tutorial at: https://boardgame.io/documentation/#/tutorial?id=validating-moves

The error I am getting is:

```
$ npm test

> great-dalmuti@1.0.0 test
> mocha

(node:21353) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)

/home/peter/Nextcloud/boardgame.io/great-dalmuti/test/Game.test.js:3
import { INVALID_MOVE } from 'boardgame.io/core';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:199:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:166:24)
    at async formattedImport (/home/peter/Nextcloud/boardgame.io/great-dalmuti/node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js:7:14)
    at async Object.exports.requireOrImport (/home/peter/Nextcloud/boardgame.io/great-dalmuti/node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js:48:32)
    at async Object.exports.loadFilesAsync (/home/peter/Nextcloud/boardgame.io/great-dalmuti/node_modules/mocha/lib/esm-utils.js:74:20)
    at async singleRun (/home/peter/Nextcloud/boardgame.io/great-dalmuti/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run-helpers.js:125:3)
    at async Object.exports.handler (/home/peter/Nextcloud/boardgame.io/great-dalmuti/node_modules/mocha/lib/cli/run.js:366:5)
```

What I find online involves renaming files with different extensions (mostly `.cjs` and `.mjs`) or adding `<script/>` tags, or making the whole project into a module by editing `package.json`. None of these options have worked so far.

I've followed the complete boardgame.io tutorial for tic-tac-toe and have gotten it working successfully. It doesn't appear to involve modules, exotic extensions, or special tags. What the tutorial doesn't involve is TDD or automated tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node cannot execute `import` and `export` statements natively. There are 2-3 ways to do it as you said in the post itself, like 1) change extension to mjs, 2) change package.json to make project a module. I think you are not able to use that properly because you are running test cases.

So, the best thing for you would be to add babel support to your repository.

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/cli @babel/core @babel/node @babel/register @babel/preset-env
```

Make a file called `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Run with:

```
mocha --compilers js:@babel/register
```

you can change the `test` script to this as well.

You can follow a more detailed blog, for example [this](https://dev.to/bnorbertjs/my-nodejs-setup-mocha--chai-babel7-es6-43ei)

Comment: Fantastic! One minor edit, apparently `--compilers` is deprecated so I used `mocha --require @babel/register` instead. https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation. But thanks so much!